# Unterminated JSX contents when using input

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```
import React from 'react';

class AjaxIO extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      count: "1"
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.count}
      </div>
    );
  }
};

export default AjaxIO;
```

This example works. But if i change return into this.

```
<div>
   <input value={this.state.count}>
</div>
```

I get an error

```
 Unterminated JSX contents
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should close `input` tag

```
<input value={this.state.count} />
                               ^^^
```

> All tags must be closed, either with the self-closing format or with a
>   corresponding closing tag

[`Self-Closing Tag`](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/self-closing-tag.html)